# How to manually edit the key of a KSDS VSAM file?

Tags: mainframe, vsam

I have a `KSDS` file. I want to change the key of the file for testing purposes. I am unable to edit the key in `File-Aid`. Is there any way to do that ?

I have searched multiple forums, unable to find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change by following procedure

- Copy your `KSDS` dataset to `ESDS` dataset in `File-Aid`.
- Edit the key part of `KSDS` in `ESDS` file now, as it is not protected/key anymore.
- Copy the edited `ESDS` file to another `KSDS` file by allocating the key length and index file.

This has worked for me. Suggest if any better approach is there.

**Edit**

Alternate Method in `File-Aid`.
Open the KSDS file on edit mode in `File-Aid`.
- Use repeat command `R` before the key or `RR` on the block of records you want to edit.
- On the newly created repetitive record(s) you can edit as per your wish on the key area.
- After editing the new repetitive record(s), delete the original record(s).
- Use `SORT` command on the command line to sort the sequence of the keys. (This will prevent from any key sequence error while editing by copying to a `PS` file or `ESDS` file.)
- Use `SAVE` command to save the edited `VSAM`.

Answer (score 1):

IDCAMS REPRO to a flat file.

Edit with ISPF Edit.

Use your shop's SORT utility to ensure the file is in key order.

IDCAMS REPRO the sorted file to VSAM KSDS.

This method does not depend on third-party tools.  Not every shop has File-Aid.

Comment: I am absolutely agree with your method. However if in case `File-Aid` is available, should I use `File-Aid` or `REPRO` in terms of faster operation and user friendliness?

Comment: @Soumendra I suggest learning both methods, but using the one most productive for you.  If your employer has a product, use it unless there is an effort to deprecate it in your shop.

Comment: I have checked your method. On this method we have to manually take care of the sequence of the keys i.e. after modifying the flat file, we should sort the file on the key field to convert properly again to `KSDS` file.

Answer (score 0):

My recollection is that FileAid doesn't allow for updating of keys. You have to insert a new record with a new key and delete the old record. Again, my recollection is poor, but I think you can trivially do that in FileAid interactively. If you want to do it in batch, some of the other suggestions to unload from the KSDS, alter, then reload make sense.